# Solve the ODE $f'(x) = \lambda \cdot f(x)^k - f(x)$ with $f(0) = \lambda$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

## Question

I would like to solve (for the function $f:[0,\infty] \rightarrow [0,\lambda]$) the following ODE:
$$
f'(x)  = \lambda \cdot f(x)^k - f(x) \mbox{ with }f(0) = \lambda,
$$
here $f(x)$ is a decreasing function which goes from $\lambda$ to $0$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to infinity. Here $\lambda \in [0,1]$ is some constant.

## Thoughts

I tried to solve this equation by looking at it as:
$$
y' =\lambda y^k - y,
$$
which yields that $y$ satisfies:
$$
\int \frac{dy}{\lambda y^k -y} = C
$$
with $C$ some constant, which then yields:
$$
\frac{\log\left(y-\lambda y^k\right) - k \log(y)}{k-1} = 0,
$$
here $\log$ denotes the natural logarithm, but this is not really satisfactory.

Comment: It is also a Bernoulli equation using substitution $u$ equals $y$ to the power $k-1$ simplifies

Comment: your solution should be $$y \left( x \right) ={\frac {1}{ \left( \lambda\,{{\rm e}^{- \left( k-1
 \right) x}}+{\it \_C1} \right) ^{ \left( k-1 \right) ^{-1}}}{{\rm e}^
{{\frac {x}{k-1}}}} \left( {{\rm e}^{{\frac {xk}{k-1}}}} \right) ^{-1}
}
$$

Comment: @eranreches $]a,b[$ is a French notation for $(a,b)$.  Please change your proposed edit.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: How do you arrive at this solution? I can just check it directly but how to come to this? + I think you made a typo with _C1?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Mister eranreches has already responded with an answer which derives your result. I will now check his answer and accept if, if it checks out (which I expect it will).

Comment: Where is $C$ gone ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your derivation. You should have

$$\int\frac{{\rm d}y}{\lambda y^{k}-y}=\int{\rm d}x$$

$$\frac{\log\left(y-\lambda y^{k}\right)-k\log y}{k-1}=x+C$$

Now setting $y=\lambda$ for $x=0$ gives you

$$C=\frac{\log\left(\lambda-\lambda^{k+1}\right)-k\log\lambda}{k-1}$$

and so

$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{y-\lambda y^{k}}{\lambda-\lambda^{k+1}}\right)-k\log\left(\frac{y}{\lambda}\right)}{k-1}=x$$

$$\frac{\log\left(\frac{y-\lambda y^{k}}{\lambda-\lambda^{k+1}}\cdot\frac{\lambda^{k}}{y^{k}}\right)}{k-1}=x$$

$$\frac{1-\lambda y^{k-1}}{1-\lambda^{k}}\cdot\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{y^{k-1}}=e^{\left(k-1\right)x}$$

Proceeding as suggested by @LutzL we get

$$\frac{y^{1-k}-\lambda}{\lambda^{1-k}-\lambda}=e^{\left(k-1\right)x}$$

$$y=\left(\lambda+\left(\lambda^{1-k}-\lambda\right)e^{\left(k-1\right)x}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-k}}$$

as a solution.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Awesome thanks all!